# Why is детей in the Gen. and not the Nom. in this у + Gen. + Nom. construction?

Tags: грамматика, родительный-падеж

Apologies for this basic question:

Why does 'детей' in 'сколько у тебя детей' appear in the gen. and not the nom. as in the usual у + gen. + nom. construction?
I wanted to ask this question as the preceding sentence read: 'у тебя есть дети' where the у + gen. + nom. seemed to work perfectly. Is it because

- (1) the 'existence' of the children is no longer in question;
- (2) that the noun [детей] must agree with the personal pronoun [тебе] in the genitive case; or
- (3) because we're now asking about the quantity of children?

Apologies, I just really want to know for sure. If anyone could explain exactly why it changes I'd be very grateful - thanks!

Comment: # 3............

Answer (score 4):

- "Сколько" – as a word denoting the **quantity** of something – takes a **genitive** noun by default.
- An associated genitive noun (like "детей") is often separated from "сколько" rather than being placed immediately following "сколько".

In one of the simplest examples, "How old are you?" – while it is perfectly acceptable to place "сколько" and the associated genitive noun "лет" side by side:

> А **сколько** **лет** тебе?

*Separated* *style* – with some pronoun (тебе, у тебя, etc) interposed –  is more commonly used:

> А **сколько** тебе **лет**?
>
> **Сколько** тебе было **лет**, когда умерла твоя мать?

Answer (score 1):

Here, сколько means quantity. Let's count.

> 1 год, 2 года, 3 года, 4 года, 5 лет, 6... лет  1 ребёнок, 2-4
>   ребёнка, 5... детей.

Сколько лет, сколько детей - **as in the biggest variant**. Don't pay attention that 21 - again год, just remember, that **сколько** requires the same form as with 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10.

The same case is with the adverbs **много**, **мало**, **несколько**.

Много людей, мало сил, несколько яблок.

So,

> У тебя есть несколько яблок? Мы сделаем пирог.
>   У нас есть много
>   друзей, и все они придут в гости.
>   У меня мало сил к вечеру, сделаю
>   работу завтра.